# How do I change this code so it only prints just one copy of each of the prime divisors

Tags: java, bluej

How do I edit this code so that it prints out only just one copy of each of the prime divisors?

```java
 public class Factors {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // command-line argument
        long n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);

        System.out.print("The prime factorization of " + n + " is: ");

        // for each potential factor
        for (long factor = 2; factor*factor <= n; factor++) {

            // if factor is a factor of n, repeatedly divide it out
            while (n % factor == 0) {
                System.out.print(factor + " "); 
                n = n / factor;
            }
        }

        // if biggest factor occurs only once, n > 1
        if (n > 1) System.out.println(n);
        else       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  You are printing out the prime factorization of the number perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop, set a `boolean` flag to control printing.

```
      for (long factor = 2; factor * factor <= n; factor++) {

         // if factor is a factor of n, repeatedly divide it out
         boolean flag = true;
         while (n % factor == 0) {
            n = n / factor;
            if (flag) {
               System.out.print(factor + " ");
               flag = false;
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

or you create a array with the olds factors, or when you find a factor you continue to divide until the remainder is zero:

```
for (long factor = 2; factor*factor <= n; factor++) {

    // if factor is a factor of n, repeatedly divide it out
    while (n % factor == 0) {
        System.out.print(factor + " "); 
        long reminder;
        do{ 
            reminder = n % factor;
            if(reminder == 0) n = n / factor; 
        } while (reminder==0 && n>1);
    }
}
```